# PHP Remove a string that starts with http:// or www and ends with .com/.ca/.net etc

Tags: php

I found a bunch of link that show how to delete anything within   with str_replace() but I want to censor the link on a post. Even better, somehow detect when the user is trying to post a link and not let them submit the form until they remove it

I am not to sure what to write inside str_replace() or how to check the page for inserted urls

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You will likely need to look at regular expressions (regex) to do this.

Comment: @Gadgetster it may be helpful if you can provide an example of what you're looking for.

Comment: @KyleChallis I thought it was straight forward.. an example: most forums delete or censor urls as they don't want external links on their site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to check the submitted string against a regular expression using preg_match().

```
preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i", $string)
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved with regular expression. A kind of pattern comparision

Like this:

```
$pattern = "/(?i)(<a([^>]+)>(.+?)<\/a>)/";
$output = preg_replace ( $pattern , "Censured link",$inputText);

//assuming $inputText contains your input
```

this will replace all anchors with the text Censured link

Comment: `<a [.]*</a>` will not do what you think it does. You probably want a lazy match: `<a .*?</a>` — but this is ***not*** guaranteed to work for all possible cases, though.

Comment: Pattern is changed. But whats wrong with the above?

Comment: `[.]` will not match any character. It will only match the literal period character (`.`).

Comment: Thats why I changed the code above. Was a bit to fast to post.

Comment: is this going to find a link on the page as well as a plain text url? I want to completely make sure there is no external url on the post

Comment: This pattern will only match html links. But you can make an other pattern to match a URL instead. But I think it won't be possible to remove all possible ways of entering a URL. Matching against an adress like http://www.stackoverflow.com or www.stackoverflow.com is not a problem but if a user begins typing an adress like: www . stackoverflow.com or stackoverflow[dot]com you're in problem. So the question is how certain you need to be that no URLs gets posted?

Comment: if the user make www . stackoverflow.com then that's fine, but if they do it the regular way, then i want it to remove it

Answer (score 0):

you can use these functions(little bit ease)

```
$link1="http://www.asda.com";
$link2="http://www.asda.net";
$link3="http://www.asda.ca";
function startsWith($to, $find)
{
    return $find=== "" || strpos($to, $find) === 0;
}
function endsWith($to, $find)
{
    return $find=== "" || substr($to, -strlen($find)) === $find;
}

var_dump(startsWith($link1, "https")); // true
var_dump(endsWith($link2, "au")); 
...so on
```

Comment: how do I feed in url's that the user will input?

Comment: once if you have the url which you want to check then you can pass it as a argument to the functions startsWith($yoururl) and endsWith($yourURL) which will return true or false.then do what you want to

Comment: can you show me what you mean in an EDIT of your answer? I don't quite understand how to check the user's input url